# Multiple WHERE statements followed by multiple columns using LIKE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using a sqlite database and currently using this sql statement to define my search in an app.

```
SELECT *
FROM 'tablename' 
WHERE type = 'type' AND
      is_real= 'true' AND
      id LIKE '%search input%' OR title LIKE '%search input%' OR body LIKE '%search input%'
ORDER BY index_id
```

what i'm trying to do is select all from `tablename` where `type` and `is_true` is equal to a specific value.... while it also returns with all the LIKE statements for my search..  but it seems to ignore the type and is_true statement when i add the LIKE/or statements

Also i know all the data is being passed correctly

Comment: You need parentheses around the `OR`s expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You need some parenthesis as because of operator priority :

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t
WHERE (type = 'type' AND is_real= 'true') AND 
      (id LIKE '%search input%' OR title LIKE '%search input%' OR body LIKE '%search input%') 
ORDER BY index_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the OR's, not the LIKEs. You just need parentheses around your LIKE statements. Otherwise if any of the ORs are true it will ignore the first two conditions.

```
SELECT *
FROM 'tablename' 
WHERE type = 'type' AND
      is_real= 'true' AND
      ( id LIKE '%search input%' OR title LIKE '%search input%' OR body LIKE '%search input%' )
ORDER BY index_id
```